# Updating HTTP header for logged in users in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nginx

We are current hosting two applications on our site `x`, `A` and `B`. We have currently setup a reverse proxy to do the routing. eg. serve pages with `/restaurants/:id` to app `A` and other pages to app `B`. Now we are encountering a situation where we need to serve page `/restaurants/:id` from app `A`, only if user is logged in.

From what I am reading this can be done based on HTTP header. Anyway we can update the HTTP header so that we can differentiated between a visitor and logged in user.

Answer (score 0):

There is no safe way to do so. HTTP is stateless, so at the reverse proxy layer, the HTTP request cannot tell you the user is actually logged in or not.

You can use a dirty hack that adds a cookie which say `isLoggedIn: true` when the user is logged in and check that cookie is included to the HTTP request or not on the reverse proxy. However, there is no guaranty that way always works, you still have to check the user is actually logged in or not at application level.

[image: Sample diagram]

Comment: Is it possible to do a reverse proxy at application layer?

Comment: You can do the redirection at application. Suppose user go `/restaurants/:id` then you can add a `before_action` to check user logged it, then redirect her to B if not. ( It's possible, but doesn't mean about reverse proxy )

Comment: ideally need a 200 not a 301

Comment: Sadly, Rails default does not support acting as a proxy. Moreover, 301 redirection is common when the user is not authenticated. The `isLoggedIn` cookie just reduce the possibility that user goes to app A.